# DSC Https Pull Server - An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: powershell, dsc

I've been struggling two weeks with the DSC Pull Server configuration. I had no success configuring an *http/https pull server* neither with *ConfigurationId* approach nor using *ConfigurationNames*

Smb Pull server was the only server configuration that worked for me, but I aspire to https.

I've ruled out some common mistakes I've read in powershell.org posts, documentation and forums:

- Checking Remoting is enabled
- Avoid using self-signed **certificates.** (I used IIS Management Console and a Root CA certificate to issue an appropriate server certificate)
- Checking **Windows Management Framework** [(WFM) versions for node-server incompatibilities][1]
- Checking **.Net Framework 4.5.2** or above is installed on Server 2012 for [WMF 5.1 to work well][2].
- **Verify Web Service** either using [Verify-DSCPullServer function][3] or pasting url https://[pullserver]:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc in the browser, then checking there aren't SSL warnings and certificate is valid

The following are the machine's configurations for my server and nodes:

**Server 2012 + WMF 5.1**

```
Name Value
—- —–
PSVersion 5.1.14409.1012
PSEdition Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion 10.0.14409.1012
CLRVersion 4.0.30319.36440
WSManStackVersion 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1
```

**Client Windows 10 Pro 1709**

```
Name Value
—- —–
PSVersion 5.1.16299.547
PSEdition Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion 10.0.16299.547
CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1
```

#### Configuration Id Approach

1. Server Configuration

   I'm using xPSDesiredConfiguration 8.4.0.0 and xDscWebService Resource to configure the Server, this way

   ```
       configuration HTTPSPullServer
       {

           param
           (
               [string[]]$NodeName = 'localhost',

               [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
               [string] $certificateThumbPrint
           )

           # Modules must exist on target pull server
           Import-DSCResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

           Node $NodeName
           {
               WindowsFeature DSCServiceFeature
               {
                   Ensure = "Present"
                   Name   = "DSC-Service"
               }

               #IIS Console
               WindowsFeature IISConsole {
                   Ensure = "Present"
                   Name   = "Web-Mgmt-Console"
               }

               xDscWebService PSDSCPullServer
               {
                   Ensure                  = "Present"
                   EndpointName            = "PSDSCPullServer"
                   Port                    = 8080
                   PhysicalPath            = "$env:SystemDrive\inetpub\wwwroot\PSDSCPullServer"
                   CertificateThumbPrint   = $certificateThumbPrint
                   ModulePath              = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\Modules"
                   ConfigurationPath       = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\Configuration"
                   State                   = "Started"
                   DependsOn               = "[WindowsFeature]DSCServiceFeature"
                   UseSecurityBestPractices = $true
               }
           }
       }

       HTTPSPullServer -NodeName vmdt01 -certificateThumbPrint '712FCD316ED524F785186DD144DD445A47CB66A5' -OutputPath E:\DSC\HTTPS\

       Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName vmdt01 -Path E:\DSC\HTTPS -Verbose -Wait -Force
   ```

   (I've tried different combination on *UseSecurityBestPractices* and *DisableSecurityBestPractices* properties without success)
2. Clients LCM Configuration (Using ConfigurationId approach)

   ```
       [DSCLocalConfigurationManager()]
       Configuration PullW10ClientsConfigId 
       {
          param
           (
                   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                   [string[]]$ComputerName,

                   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
                   [string]$guid
           )

           Node $ComputerName {

               Settings {

                   RefreshMode = 'Pull'
                       RefreshFrequencyMins = 30
                               ConfigurationMode = 'ApplyAndAutoCorrect'
                               RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
                   ConfigurationID = $guid
               }

                   ConfigurationRepositoryWeb DSCHTTPS {
                       ServerURL = 'https://vmdt01.dggh.es:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc'
                       CertificateID = '712FCD316ED524F785186DD144DD445A47CB66A5'
                   }

                   ReportServerWeb ReportServer {
                       ServerURL = 'https://vmdt01.dggh.es:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc'
                       CertificateID = '712FCD316ED524F785186DD144DD445A47CB66A5'
                       AllowUnsecureConnection = $True

                   }

           }
       }
   ```
3. Rename MOF files to match configurationId and apply

   ```
   `New-DSCChecsum`
   ```
4. When I try to do

   ```
   `Update-StartDscConfiguration -Computer vcontab1-w10 -Wait -Verbose`
   ```

   I get the following errors and stack trace on the **event viewer**:


   Trabajo {B3C00709-9C7A-11E8-ACE3-000C2991FEC5}:
   Comando Do-DscAction de WebDownloadManager para configuración e2665f67-3a61-4989-9870-616a065298d6, resultado de llamada GET:
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebDownloadManagerGetActionFailed
   + CategoryInfo : InvalidResult: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
   + ExceptionMessage : **No se pudo obtener la acción del servidor https://vmdt01.dggh.es:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc/Action(ConfigurationId='e2665f67-3a61-4989-9870-616a065298d6')/GetAction**.
   + InnerException : System.AggregateException: Se han producido uno o varios errores. ---> **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud**. ---> **System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío**. ---> **System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto**. ---> **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto**
   en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   en System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   en Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.Commands.GetDscActionCommand.IssueRequest(IHttpClient client, String subLink, String& responseStatus, ErrorRecord& errorRecord)
   ---> (Nº de excepción interna 0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud. ---> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
   en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   en System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---<---

   Where error in English are:

       **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request
       System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: unexpected error
       System.IO.IOException: Cannot write data to the transport connection: The remote host forced the interruption of an exixting connection**

Whilst if I use *Configuration Names* approach I get the error earlier, during the node registration.

#### Configuration Name Approach

1. Server Configuration

   ```
       configuration HTTPSPullServer
       {
           param
           (
               [string[]]$NodeName = 'localhost',

               [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
               [string] $certificateThumbPrint,

               [Parameter(HelpMessage='This should be a string with enough entropy (randomness) to protect the registration of clients to the pull server.  We will use new GUID by default.')]
               [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
               [string] $RegistrationKey   # A guid that clients use to initiate conversation with pull server
           )

           # Modules must exist on target pull server
           Import-DSCResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

           Node $NodeName
           {
               WindowsFeature DSCServiceFeature
               {
                   Ensure = "Present"
                   Name   = "DSC-Service"
               }

               #Consola de IIS
               WindowsFeature IISConsole {
                   Ensure = "Present"
                   Name   = "Web-Mgmt-Console"
                   DependsOn = '[File]RegistrationKeyFile'
               }

               xDscWebService PSDSCPullServer
               {
                   Ensure                  = "Present"
                   EndpointName            = "PSDSCPullServer"
                   Port                    = 8080
                   PhysicalPath            = "$env:SystemDrive\inetpub\wwwroot\PSDSCPullServer"
                   CertificateThumbPrint   = $certificateThumbPrint
                   ModulePath              = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\Modules"
                   ConfigurationPath       = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\Configuration"
                   RegistrationKeyPath      = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\WindowsPowerShell\DscService"
                   State                   = "Started"
                   DependsOn               = "[WindowsFeature]DSCServiceFeature"
                   UseSecurityBestPractices = $true          
               }

               File RegistrationKeyFile
               {
                   Ensure          = 'Present'
                   Type            = 'File'
                   DestinationPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\RegistrationKeys.txt"
                   Contents        = $RegistrationKey
               }
           }
       }

       # Generate MOF
       HTTPSPullServer -NodeName vmdt01 -certificateThumbPrint '9F00EDBDFB791C7AAD9200E9E0BA8FD59684B419' -RegistrationKey 'e2665f67-3a61-4989-9870-616a065298d6' -OutputPath E:\DSC\HTTPS\

       Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName vmdt01 -Path E:\DSC\HTTPS -Verbose -Wait -Force
   ```
2. Client LCM (Configuration Name Approach)

   ```
       [DSCLocalConfigurationManager()]
       Configuration PullW10ClientsConfigNames 
       {
          param
           (
               [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
               [string] $NodeName = 'localhost',

               [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
               [string] $RegistrationKey #same as the one used to setup pull server in previous configuration

           )
           Node $NodeName {

               Settings {

                   RefreshMode = 'Pull'
                       RefreshFrequencyMins = 30
                               ConfigurationMode = 'ApplyAndAutoCorrect'
                               RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
               }

                   ConfigurationRepositoryWeb DSCHTTPS {
                       ServerURL = 'https://vmdt01.dggh.es:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc'
                       RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
                       ConfigurationNames = @('w10client')
                       AllowUnsecureConnection = $false
                   }

                   ReportServerWeb ReportServer {
                       ServerURL = 'https://vmdt01.dggh.es:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc'
                       CertificateID = '712FCD316ED524F785186DD144DD445A47CB66A5'
                       AllowUnsecureConnection = $false
                   }
           }
       }

       # Create the Computer.Meta.Mof in folder
       PullW10ClientsConfigNames -NodeName vcontab1-w10 -RegistrationKey 'e2665f67-3a61-4989-9870-616a065298d6' -OutputPath E:\DSC\HTTPS

       Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -ComputerName vcontab1-w10 -Path E:\DSC\HTTPS -Verbose
   ```

   At this point, I get an error saying the DSC Agent with an specific AgentId could not be registered on the server.

   Here's the event log throwing the same errors than in the ConfigurationId approach


   Trabajo {0EE9AD70-9C80-11E8-ACE3-000C2991FEC5} :
   el cliente HTTP 3A1CC07C-9BC1-11E8-ACE3-000C2991FEC5 no pudo registrar el agente de Dsc:
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterDscAgentCommandFailed
   + CategoryInfo : InvalidResult: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
   + ExceptionMessage : **No se pudo registrar el agente de Dsc con AgentId 3A1CC07C-9BC1-11E8-ACE3-000C2991FEC5 con el servidor https://vmdt01.dggh.es:8080/PSDSCPullServer.svc/Nodes(AgentId='3A1CC07C-9BC1-11E8-ACE3-000C2991FEC5')**.
   + InnerException : System.AggregateException: Se han producido uno o varios errores. ---> **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud. ---> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto**
   en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   en System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   en Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.Commands.RegisterDscAgentCommand.IssueRequest(DotNetHttpClient client, String subLink, ErrorRecord& errorRecord)
   ---> (Nº de excepción interna 0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud. ---> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto
   en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   en System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---<---

May somebody give me a hint of where could be the matter?
Is it an issue with security protocols? Might be something related to Server 2012 OS, which was the first version that supported DSC? I'd really appreciate some help here.

I've been suggested to use *Wireshark* to check whether it's a **TLS version issue**. I cannot assure or deny it has to be with TLS, but what is sure, is it's a security problem. Sniffing the response to the registration request of a node, there's a message like this:

> MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/encrypted,
>   Boundary: "Encrypted Boundary" The multipart dissector could not
>   decrypt the message

I don't think it has to be with TLS, because I have enabled TLS 1.0 and 1.2 in the Client by modifying the appropriate [registry settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings).

Comment: You have a very long question, so I'm going to ask two simple questions: when you generate the configuration for the node, are you giving it a GUID and configuring the node's LCM to match?  Are you generating a new checksum on the DSC pull server for the mof?

Comment: Hello, the answer to both of your questions is Yes.  But I found out the problem was an incompatibility with my Access Driver. I had to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2012. You can read more about it in this entry https://powershell.org/forums/topic/dsc-https-pull-server-an-error-occurred-while-sending-the-request/